# Como calcular e exibir a soma das datas instantaneamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Caros,

Tenho uma situação onde preciso criar um contrato de locação. Nos campos, a pessoa que está entrando com os dados tem as opções:

*meses / *data inicial / *data término

Gostaria de saber como fazer isso em JavaScript, com atualização instantânea. Testei com [essa solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87758/35950), mas sem sucesso, pois creio que se trata apenas de números inteiros.

[image: Formulário que mostra uma data inicial e um acréscimo em meses. Logo abaixo, uma data de término, calculada em função da data inicial e do acréscimo]

Gostei do método `onblur`, pois o resultado é gerado automaticamente, baseado na escolha do usuário.

Preciso de uma luz!

Comment: qual a formula de calculo? o que você quer calcular? Pode dar um exemplo de saída?

Comment: Claro! Um exemplo: 28/03/2016 + 6 meses = 28/09/2016 (não exatamente, considerando meses com 30 ou 31 dias)

Answer (score 2):

Aconselho a utilização do `.change` em cima do drop com a quantidade de meses.

Você tendo a string com a data inicial, podes criar um `Date()` com essa string...e a partir daí somar a quantidade de meses.

E claro, você também vai precisar de uma formação da data, que eu aconselho essa:

```
function formatarData(data) {
    var d = new Date(data),
        mes = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        dia = '' + d.getDate(),
        ano = d.getFullYear();

    if (mes.length < 2) mes = '0' + mes;
    if (dia.length < 2) dia = '0' + dia;

    return [dia, mes, ano].join('/');
}
```

Ou seja, com sua entrada:

```
var qtdMeses = 6;
var dtInicio = new Date($("#dataInicio").val());
dtInicio.setMonth(dtInicio.getMonth() + qtdMeses); //adicionando meses

$("#dataTermino").val(formatarData(dtInicio));
```

**EDIT**:

a `dtInicio` também tem que ser formatada antes de ser utilizada... atualizei a atribuição dela da seguinte forma:

```
var dtInicio = new Date(formatarData($("#dataInicio").val()));
```

[Exemplo online](https://jsfiddle.net/tretaa/22ryrb6f/)

**OUTRO EDIT:**

Conforme falei nos comentários, acho a melhor solução adicionar N dias (visto que, no dia 30 de janeiro se eu adicionar + 1 mês, irá retornar `NaN`, pois não existe dia 30 de fevereiro... Sendo assim, preparei outro [Exemplo Online](https://jsfiddle.net/tretaa/22ryrb6f/3/) e fiz uma mudança na estrutura dos eventos. Criei uma função para fazer o cálculo da data....essa função é chamada toda vez que o evento `change()` do dropdown da quantidade de meses for `"triggado"` e toda vez que o campo da data de início perde o foco (`blur`).

```
$("#meses").change(function() {
    calcularDataTermino();
});

$("#dataInicio").blur(function() {
    calcularDataTermino();
});

function calcularDataTermino() {
  var qtdMeses = parseInt($("#meses").val());
  var qtdDias = 30 * parseInt($("#meses").val()); // sempre 30 dias + de acordo com a quantidade de meses: 1 mês = +30 dias; 2 meses = + 60 dias; 3 meses = 90 dias;
  var dtInicio = new Date(formatarData($("#dataInicio").val()));


  //dtInicio.setMonth(dtInicio.getMonth() + qtdMeses); //+ N qtdMeses
  dtInicio.setDate(dtInicio.getDate() + qtdDias); //+ N dias

  $("#dataTermino").val(formatarData(dtInicio));
}
```

Comment: Amigo! Vou implantar e retorno com o resultado. Obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Comment: Editei a implementação pois a data inicial também precisa ser formatada, dê uma olhada.. boa sorte! Não é melhor utilizar a adição em dias, @HebertRichard? Adicionar sempre N dias (baseado nos meses)

Comment: Ok @Marllon, vou verificar e retorno com a solução ou dúvida. Grande abraço!

Comment: @HebertRichard, fiz outra edição na resposta adicionando outro exemplo para cálculo, desta vez adicionando "n" dias.... acho que tem tudo que você precisa aí...